# how to take distinct with minimum value using xslt1.0?

Tags: xslt

Below is my xml file called product.xml

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <price>8</price>
    </product> 
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <price>10</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <price>10</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <price>5</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <price>15</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pencil</name>
        <price>5</price>
    </product>
    </products>
```

I need to take distinct product with there minimum price ...using xslt 1.0

required output is

```
<products>
<product>
    <name>Bag</name>
    <price>10</price>
</product>
<product>
    <name>Pen</name>
    <price>5</price>
</product>
<product>
    <name>Pencil</name>
    <price>5</price>
</product>
<products>
```

hoping your help ----------------------------------------------------------------    --------------------------------------- -   ------------------------------------------------------------------- - -  ------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kProdByName" match="product"
           use="name"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "product
    [generate-id()
    =
     generate-id(key('kProdByName', name)[1])
     ]
  ">
   <product>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('kProdByName', name)">
      <xsl:sort select="price" data-type="number"/>

      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </product>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <price>8</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <price>10</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <price>10</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <price>5</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <price>15</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Pencil</name>
        <price>5</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<product>
  <name>Pen</name>
  <price>5</price>
</product>
<product>
  <name>Bag</name>
  <price>10</price>
</product>
<product>
  <name>Pencil</name>
  <price>5</price>
</product>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Muenchian grouping of `product` by `name`.
2. In each group finding the `product` with minimum `price` by taking the first `product` from the groups sorted node-list.